# How to test actor with patterns pipe

Tags: akka

I have an actor, that receive message from initiator, then ask worker, and finally sends result to initiator.

It's more clearly in the code:

```
public class MyActor extends UntypedActor {

    private final ActorRef worker;

    public MyActor(ActorRef worker) {
        this.worker = worker;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
        if ("initiate".equals(message)) {
            final ActorRef initiator = sender();
            final Future f = Patterns.ask(worker, "ask:"+message, Timeout.apply(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
            Patterns.pipe(f, context().system().dispatcher()).to(initiator);
        }
    }
}
```

**And now try to test this actor.**

What I need to test(correct me, if i wrong):

1) When "initiate" receive, worker should receive "ask:initiate"
2) When "responseFromWorker" receive, initiator should receive "responseFromWorker"

And test:

```
@Test
public void testIt() {
    new JavaTestKit(system) {
        {

            JavaTestKit initiator = new JavaTestKit(system);
            JavaTestKit worker = new JavaTestKit(system);

            final Props props = Props.create(MyActor.class, worker.getRef());
            final ActorRef subject = system.actorOf(props);

            subject.tell("initiate", initiator.getRef());

            worker.expectMsgEquals("ask:initiate");

            subject.tell("responseFromWorker", worker.getRef());

            //this fails
            initiator.expectMsgEquals("responseFromWorker");

        }
    };
}
```

**upd**

Initiator not receive message:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: timeout (3 seconds) during expectMsg while waiting for responseFromWorker
```

Though my actors's code correct:

```
static class Worker extends UntypedActor {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Throwable {
        if (message.equals("ask:initiate"))
            sender().tell("responseFromWorker", self());
    }
}

static class Initiator extends UntypedActor {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Throwable {
        if (message.equals("responseFromWorker"))
            System.out.println("Initiator receive responseFromWorker");
    }
}

@Test
public void noAkkaTestKit() {

    final ActorRef worker = system.actorOf(Props.create(Worker.class));

    final ActorRef initiator = system.actorOf(Props.create(Initiator.class));

    final ActorRef subject = system.actorOf(Props.create(MyActor.class, worker));

    subject.tell("initiate", initiator);

}
```

So I doing something wrong. How to test it properly with `JavaTestKit`?

Comment: What have you tried? On which line does your test fail? Have you added some log statements across your code to see where it goes wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because ask future pattern will create a new actor to recieve the response msg, so the code

```
subject.tell("responseFromWorker", worker.getRef());
```

will send the message directly to the subject, not to that actor.

You can send msg to the last msg sender of the test probe

I write a scala version

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

import akka.actor.{Props, Actor, ActorRef, ActorSystem}
import akka.pattern.{ask, pipe}
import akka.testkit.{TestProbe, ImplicitSender, TestKit}
import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfterAll, BeforeAndAfterEach, Matchers, WordSpecLike}

class MyActor(worker: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  import context.dispatcher
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case message@"initiate" =>
      val initiator = sender()
      println("received " + message)
      val f = ask(worker, "ask:" + message)(akka.util.Timeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
      f pipeTo initiator
    case msg =>
      println(msg)
  }
}

class ActorSpec extends TestKit(ActorSystem("MySpec"))
  with ImplicitSender with WordSpecLike with BeforeAndAfterAll with BeforeAndAfterEach with Matchers {
  val workerProbe = TestProbe()
  val initiatorProbe = TestProbe()

  val props = Props(new MyActor(workerProbe.ref))
  val subject = system.actorOf(props)

  subject.tell("initiate", initiatorProbe.ref)
  workerProbe.expectMsg("ask:initiate")
  workerProbe.sender.tell("responseFromWorker", workerProbe.ref)
  initiatorProbe.expectMsg("responseFromWorker")
}
```

Comment: Excellent! I missed important line in documentation about ask future pattern.